# Cron Expression to start at 15 minutes when the application starts

Tags: cron, cron-task

How to set a cron that starts 15 minutes after the application starts and then runs for every 1 hour.
This is what I have done

```
15 */1 * * * ?
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible only by raw cron query.

You've got two problems:

First is you have to do something to delay your query to run after 15 minutes.

Second is the query that will vary depends on time your application had beed started. I think you can't solve your second problem without constructing query manually each time (of course you can compute it).

Let's assume that your application started at 14:27

so your query have to be something like that `42 */1 * * * ?`

EDIT:
Potential solution

1. Define script that will run after application starts and register in scheduler one time task after (Make sure it's supported by your cron scheduler)
2. That script compute value that have to be computed (15 + your application start time I wrote you earlier) and register another script with properly computed cron expression.

Third script that have buisness logic that have to be performed and is registered in second expression (that computed)